# Infusionsoft to CiviCRM data migration

Tags: wordpress, import

I am a digital marketing consultant and I have a non-profit client who is looking to migrate from Infusionsoft to Civi.  I am working with a certified implementation partner however she doesn't like doing data migration.  Her exact words were "it drives me to drink". This is also the first time I would be using CiviCRM myself.

I haven't found any reference to this online, except for one Ukranian company that says they do it: https://www.data2crm.com   - I assume no one has heard of these guys?

Can anyone offer suggestions or tips about the best way to implement the migration?

Just some numbers I pulled from Infusionosft:
18,878 Contacts
No Leads, Opportunities, Tasks, Notes, Attachments, Calls or Meetings because no one trained them how to use Infusionsoft properly in the first place
56,000 emails sent in the past 30 days with a 25% open rate.
They have 357 Action sets, 25 Tag Categories and 578 Tags.  What kind of fields would this kind of data migrate to in CiviCRM.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is this "certified implementation partner"

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find some support I am sure there are other CiviCRM partners that would be happy to assist with migration? I know we would if we have the time and if it makes sense :-)
As you might know the biggest pitfall in migration is to make the switch in thought patterns. When looking at source data you are in the thought pattern of the 'old' system and when you start looking for where the data should go in CiviCRM you remain in the 'old' thought pattern. Really you should know some of the basic processes in CiviCRM before you even start thinking about what fields the data should go to. My recommendation would be to start there, and not with 'what field should this go to'. That drives me to drink :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look through the list of partners on the CiviCRM website and see if any of them are able to help:

[Partners and contributors](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors)